# The infamous 'function' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, oop, header, scope

I know this has been asked many times, but I can not understand this problem. This my header file:

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

#include "storage_adaptors.hpp"
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>

class Task {
private:
    boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> taskPosistionConstraint;
    boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> initialPosition;
    boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> finalPosition;
    double pathLength;
    int taskType;

public:
    Task();
    Task(double* _initialPoint, double* _finalPoint, int type);
    double getLength();
    int getTaskType();

    ~Task();
};

#endif  /* TASK_H */
```

and this is the cpp file:

```
#include "Task.h"


const int TASK_SIZE = 3;

Task::Task() {
}

Task::~Task() {
}

Task::Task(double* _initialPoint, double* _finalPoint, int type) {

    finalPosition = make_vector_from_pointer(TASK_SIZE,_finalPoint);
    initialPosition = make_vector_from_pointer(TASK_SIZE, _initialPoint);

}
```

The error occurs at `make_vector_from_pointer` function that is defined in the `storage_adaptors.hpp` which is included in the `Task.h` which is a `boost hpp file`.
If the header is added to the class header file, why I'm having out of scope error:

> Task.cpp:21: error: `make_vector_from_pointer' was not declared in
>   this scope

Comment: `boost::numeric::ublas::make_vector_from_pointer` or `using namespace boost::numeric::ublas` in `cpp`

Comment: can you show us the missing declarations?

Comment: also, having a class "Task" and a method "Task" is not a great idea to begin with

Comment: @maverik, But, in that header file, the namespace is already added. Should I do it by myself again?

Comment: @Filip, it's the constructor of the class.

Comment: Pedantic point - identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved in both C and C++. Also identifiers containing double-underscores. If you want a prefix convention for parameters, the most common is either `p` or `p_`. It can be confusing in combination with Hungarian (which uses `p` for pointer) but the Hungarian convention is rarely used in C++ anyway.

Comment: why don't you show the relevant declarations in `storage_adaptors.hpp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a boost function, shouldn't it be `boost::make_vector_from_pointer'` ? Or whatever namespace it's in if not directly in the boost namespace.

Comment: But, in that header file, the namespace is already added. Should I do it by myself again?

Comment: @Pouya: Do you mean that there is a `using namespace boost;` declaration in the header file? I don't think so. If I am right, then JohnB's suggestion will fix your problem.

Comment: it IS in the header, however, adding namespace in the body of constructor solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: A common style rule - `using namespace ...;` should never be used in a header file, unless enclosed in some scope-limiting block.